# ngModel don't upate deep level

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When I have a ngModel with more that one level and I modify the value programmatically in the scope, the value is not updated in the UI. If I put a $watch on the same property, it works. How can I fix ngModel

html:

```
<form ng-controller="testController">
    <input type="text" ng-model="coco.c.c.c">
    <input type="test" ng-model="super.s.s.s">
    <input type="test" ng-model="super2">
</form>
```

js:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('testController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.super = {
        s: {
            s: {

            }
        }
    };

    $scope.coco = {
        c: {
            c: {

            }
        }
    };

    $scope.$watch('coco.c.c.c', function (value) {
        $scope.super = +value * 2;
        console.log(value);

    });
    $scope.$watch('super.s.s.s', function (value) {
        $scope.super2 = +value * 2;
    });
});
app.controller('testController2', function ($scope) {
    $scope.$watch('coco', function (value) {
        $scope.super = +value * 2;
        console.log(value);
    });
    $scope.$watch('super', function (value) {
        $scope.super2 = +value * 2;
    });
});
```

angular.bootstrap(document, [app.name]);

http://jsfiddle.net/M5wzt/2/

Comment: you've got one to many .c in your ng-model. You have coco.c.c.c, shouldn't it be coco.c.c?

Comment: no, my ngModel is bound on coco.c.c.c and my watch is bound on coco.c.c.c. The watch gets called, but my ngModel doesn't get updated

Comment: From a quick look I suspect this is a nested scope issue. Some info here: http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/14/nested-scopes-in-angularjs.html

Comment: I understand what you're binding your ng-model and watch to, but your object model is $scope.coco.c.c, not coco.c.c.c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is this line

```
  $scope.super = +value * 2;
```

here you are changing what $scope.super is. So You can no more use $scope.super.s.s.s

I have not understood what is that you want to accomplish, though. Maybe something like this?

```
<form ng-controller="testController">
   <input type="text" ng-model="coco.c.c.c" />
   <input type="text" ng-model="super.s.s.s" />
   <input type="text" ng-model="super2" />
</form>

app.controller('testController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.super = {s:{ s:{ }}}

    $scope.coco = {
        c: {
            c: {

            }
        }
    };

    $scope.$watch('coco.c.c.c', function (value) {
        $scope.super.s.s.s = +value * 2;
        console.log("coco", value);

    });
    $scope.$watch('super.s.s.s', function (value) {
       $scope.super2 = +value * 2;
        console.log("super", value);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

continuing the previous answer. On line

```
$scope.super = +value * 2;
```

you are adding an object to a number creating a nan value, destroying your model reference hence no model since objects are attache and watched by reference this means your input has no model to watch to hence you are braking your chain

http://jsfiddle.net/d65yan/M5wzt/4/

and then you are trying to listen in a controller for changes in the other controllers scope?? thats not going to work sorry you can only watch for thing happening in your scope